# What is the "natural" smooth structure on the subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that are topological manifolds?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Most of the differential topology book describe a manifold that is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and without describing the smooth structure, they talk about their properties as smooth manifolds, such as a square which is mentioned in a question in Lee's book on p75.

What is the "natural" smooth structure on the subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that are topological manifolds ? Can you explicitly specify it ?

For example, if we were talking about the "natural" topology on the subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, it would be the topology generated by the basis whose elements are the intersection of open balls with that subset; so now the topic is about smooth structure on those topological manifolds.

Comment: Do you possibly mean open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @lush No. I'm asking specifially the closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, such as square.

Comment: @onurcanbektas: Note that the question in Lee's book doesn't treat the square as a smooth manifold or something which has smooth structure (although this is possible in the context of manifolds with corners). It asks about a diffeomorphism of the **ambient** space $\mathbb{R}^2$ which maps a certain subset to another subset.

Comment: @levap To be able to diffeomorphism, do we not need spaces to be smooth manifolds ? After all, diffeomorphisms should preserve the smooth structure ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas: You do, but the question asks to show that there is no diffeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (which has a natural smooth structure) which maps a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ (circle) to a set $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ (boundary of a square). This is a legitimate question to ask for any two subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$, you don't need to endow them with a topology or a smooth structure.